# How to use a c++ .dll in a c++ project in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2019

I am doing a school project and my teacher has given me a c++ `.dll` file and it's respective `.h` file.

How do i use it in my c++ console application with visual studio 2019?
Thanks

Comment: Did your teacher not also give you instructions on how to use it along with the .h/.dll?

Comment: He gave me only the instructions on hot to use the functions in it but no how to implements the dll into the project

Comment: @FaustoSánchezHoya Unless the assignment is specifically to teach you how to access DLLs dynamically without a static import `.lib` file, then he is not doing his job correctly by not providing that file to you.

Comment: Is the .dll file a C++/CLR DLL? Because then you don't need the .lib

Answer (score 0):

If you were not given a `.lib` file in addition to the `.h` and `.dll` files then you will likely need to go the `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress` route.  This will be a pain if the exported functions are actually decorated with C++ name mangling.

```
HINSTANCE hMyLib = LoadLibrary(_T("mydll.dll"));
if (!hMyLib) { /* error */ }
bool (*func)() = reinterpret_cast<bool (*)()>(GetProcAddress(hMyLib, "some_func"));
if (!func) { /* error */ }
if (!func()) // actual function call
{}
```

Note that it *is* possible to generate a `.lib` file yourself using the [lib.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/lib-reference?view=vs-2019) tool. You would then add the `.lib` file to the project references (either in the project settings or via a `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` directive) and you would then simply `#include` the header and be able to call the functions as if they were part of your project.